# how to keep $_POST after submitting form with onchange event?

Tags: javascript, php

I have a list view and grid view which are submit buttons and I have sort selection if I click on one of the select options the form will be submitted but I want to keep $_POST value whether the list had been clicked or Grid because when I submit the form the data will be gone

I want something like:
**Name had been clicked and list had been clicked before that**

[image]

[live example:](http://www.lenmar.com/mp3-ipod/cowon/iaudio-x5l) (I changed it but concept is the same)

I cannot remove onchange submit of select drop down and simply first choose the drop down selection and then submit the buttons because I need it to be like that for when going to the option load the form with new information

The reason why I am submitting on onchange is that I need it because I sort my items with this submit

my question is how can I have them both? do I need two forms? do I need to use jQuery?
or php will do the work?

I kept value of  option after submit by javascript but I don't know how to maintain the value of $_POST that which one had been clicked

how can I keep $_POST value when it has been set and submit the form on onchange of sort?

```
 <form method="post" action="">
    <div id="gridSort">
        <span>View Results As:</span> <span>
        <input type="submit" class="listButtons" name="view" value="List"> </span> <span>
        <input  type="submit" class="resultButtons" name="view" value="Grid"></span>
         <select id="sortSelect" class="sortSelect" size="1" name="sort" onchange="this.form.submit();">
                <option selected>Sort</option>
                <option value="Name">Name</option>
                <option value="PriceLowToHigh">Price - Low</option>
                <option value="PriceHighToLow">Price - High</option>
        </select> 
    </div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('sortSelect').value ="<?php if(! $_POST['sort']):?>"Sort"<?php  else:  echo $_POST['sort']; endif;?>";
</script>
<?php
if(isset($_POST["view"])):
if($_POST["view"]=="Grid")
{
    echo "Grid clicked";
    echo "<br/>";
}
if($_POST["view"]=="List" )
{
    echo "List clicked";
    echo "<br/>";
}
endif;
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did for someone who will become frustrated like me:

```
<form method="post" action="" id="myform">
    <div id="gridSort">
    <input type="hidden" name="selected_sort" value="<?php echo !empty($_POST['sort']) ? strip_tags($_POST['sort']) : ''; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="selectionList_view" value="<?php echo !empty($_POST['Listview']) ? strip_tags($_POST['Listview']) : ''; ?>" />
   <input  type="hidden" name="selectionGrid_view" value="<?php echo !empty($_POST['Gridview']) ? strip_tags($_POST['Gridview']) : ''; ?>" />
        <span>View Results As:</span> <span>
        <input type="submit" class="listButtons" name="Lisview" value="List"> </span> <span>
        <input  type="submit" class="resultButtons" name="Gridview" value="Grid"></span>
         <select id="sortSelect" class="sortSelect" size="1" name="sort" onchange="this.form.submit();" >
                <option selected>Sort</option>
                <option value="Name">Name</option>
                <option value="PriceLowToHigh">Price - Low</option>
                <option value="PriceHighToLow">Price - High</option>
        </select> 
    </div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('sortSelect').value ="<?php if(! $_POST['sort']):?>"Sort"<?php  else:  echo $_POST['sort']; endif;?>";
</script>
<pre>
<?php print_r($_POST); ?>
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a hidden field to your form:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <input name="selected_sort" value="<?php echo !empty($_POST['sort']) ? strip_tags($_POST['sort']) : ''; ?>" />
    <input name="selected_view" value="<?php echo !empty($_POST['view']) ? strip_tags($_POST['view']) : ''; ?>" />
    <div id="gridSort">
        <span>View Results As:</span> <span>
        <input type="submit" class="listButtons" name="view" value="List"> </span> <span>
        <input  type="submit" class="resultButtons" name="view" value="Grid"></span>
         <select id="sortSelect" class="sortSelect" size="1" name="sort" onchange="this.form.submit();">
                <option selected>Sort</option>
                <option value="Name">Name</option>
                <option value="PriceLowToHigh">Price - Low</option>
                <option value="PriceHighToLow">Price - High</option>
        </select> 
    </div>
</form>
```

This will allow the data to be sent across in all subsequent form submits

Comment: it doesn't matter the data with hidden form will be gone too whats the difference?

Comment: It will not be gone, it will be submitted with the form and can be accessed with: 

`if (!empty($_POST['selected_sort'] || !empty($_POST['view']) { // do something }`

Comment: no it will not you are not getting what I am saying first of all it is not hidden if you wanted to do hidden you should have said type="hidden" second of all when you submit the form by onchange the data will be lost!!! even in hidden no difference! at all

Comment: it can only affect the sort and show the sort value because I myself maintained it from before by javascript

Comment: I changed your code and I realized you are mostly right but I changed it alot, however thank you for help I posted my answer too

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="GET" action="">
 <body  >
<div id="gridSort">
    <span>View Results As:</span> <span>
    <input type="submit" class="listButtons" name="view" value="List"> </span> <span>
    <input  type="submit" class="resultButtons" name="view" value="Grid"></span>
     <select id="sortSelect" class="sortSelect" size="1" name="sort" onchange="this.form.submit();">
            <option selected>Sort</option>
            <option value="Name">Name</option>
            <option value="PriceLowToHigh">Price - Low</option>
            <option value="PriceHighToLow">Price - High</option>
    </select> 
</div> </body>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('sortSelect').value ="<?php if(isset( $_GET['sort'])){ echo      $_GET['sort']; } ?>";
</script>
<?php
if(isset($_GET["view"])){
if($_GET["view"]=="Grid")
{
echo "Grid clicked";
echo "<br/>";
}
if($_GET["view"]=="List" )
{
    echo "List clicked";
   echo "<br/>";
}
}
?>
```

I TRIED TO REWRITE YOUR CODE WORKS FINE, but you need to replace post method with get, this will help user on reference and page refresh as many as he want.